# ActiveRecord nested attributes, assignment auto-saves to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

Is there a way to assign value to a specific attribute in a model which is declared as a nested attribute without instantly saving it in the database? (e.g. keep it in the memory first)

Comment: just to clarify, is this a join model (`has_many :through`) or just a `has_many` ?

Comment: actually it's an has_one

Comment: hmm, the nested model shouldn't save until the parent model is saved... Are you calling `.save` or `.update_attributes` on the main model ?

Comment: hmm do you mind posting some sample code as to how you are initializing your models and setting your attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Quotied from => http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

`"Note that the :autosave option is automatically enabled on every association that #accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for."`

You cant do that using nested attributes but there are other ways. Could you first describe your exact situateion please?!

Comment: I'm using formtastic in order to manipulate a specific model's attributes and it requires me to use accepts_nested_attributes in order to manipulate another nested model. The problem is that when that model is nil (e.g. not set for the main model) it won't show up it's fields. So it's mendatory for me to set it up before the view is rendered. but When I assign something to it, it's automatically saved to the database...